# Delete Entry from the database onclick in C# MVC Entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller, routes

I am trying to delete and entry from my database by click a delete link. I am also trying to use entity framework:

Here is what I have in my controller:

```
    public ActionResult DeleteUserUserList(string UserName)
    {

        using (UsersContext db = new UsersContext())
        {
            //var username = db.UserProfile.UserName; 
            db.Entry(UserName).State = 
            System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted;
            db.SaveChanges(); 
        }

        return RedirectToAction("UserList", "Account", new {UserName = 
        UserName}); 
    }
```

Then my model looks like this:

```
public class UsersContext : DbContext
    {
        public UsersContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Membership> Membership { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    }

    [Table("UserProfile")]
    public class UserProfile
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
```

And this is what my view looks like:

```
@model IEnumerable<ComtrexCloudReporting.Models.UserProfile>


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "UserList";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h2 class="admin-home-link orange-titles">@Html.ActionLink("User 
 Information", "AdminIndex")</h2>
<p>&nbsp;</p>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{

    <p class=" col-sm-4 userNameUserList">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => 
    item.UserName) </p>
    <p class="col-sm-4 to-link"><span style="color: #f05322">|</span> <a 
    href="@string.Format("mailto:{0}", 
    item.Email)">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)</a></p>
    <p class="col-sm-4 to-link"><span style="color: #f05322">|</span> <span 
    onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete?')"><a class="back-link" 
    href="/Account/DeleteUserUserList?UserName=@item.UserName">Delete</a> 
    </p>


    }
```

I'm getting the error that the type String is not part of the model for the current context. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? It is breaking at this point right here: db.Entry(UserName).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have a `DbSet<string>` (and you can not have), thus the string is not an database entity. You need to first find you `UserProfile` entity:

```
var userProfile = context.UserProfiles.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == userName);
```

...and then, [remove](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbset.remove?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) it:

```
context.UserProfiles.Remove(userProfile);
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your response. I'm getting an error that Remove is undefined: this is what I have tried:          public ActionResult DeleteUserUserList(string UserName)
        {
            
            using (UsersContext context = new UsersContext())
            {
                var userProfile = context.UserProfiles.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == UserName);
                context.Remove(userProfile); 
            }

            return RedirectToAction("UserList", "Account", new {UserName = UserName}); 
        }

Comment: @MeganMeluskey Sorry, in EF Core you can do it by accessing the context directly. I updated my answer to use the Remove() method of the DbSet<> instead..

Comment: Hey thanks again that was helpful. However, it is not giving me any error messages and it is passing a value through the controller but when the page redirects the entry is still there. Do you have any idea what could be causing this problem?

Comment: @MeganMeluskey Have you remembered to call context.SaveChanges() ?

Comment: ahh good call i was trying to use context.UserProfile.SaveChanges() let me try that